Invisible aliens mistaken for red balloons
Looking for the title of a short story, likely from Amazing Stories Magazine, about red balloons that turn out to be the full stomachs of blood sucking invisible aliens.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is this the story where the hero "befriends" one of the balloons?

Maybe. I think the main character is a young boy.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTgkaLxkBM0 Does it end tragically when one of them meets a spiny porcupine?
